# Gevent-socketio wildcard namespace

Tags: socket.io, gevent, gevent-socketio

Is there any way in gevent to enable wildcard namespace? Maybe something like `namespace/**wildcard**`. I tried to look at gevent's documentation:

```
from socketio.namespace import BaseNamespace

class ChatNamespace(BaseNamespace):
    ...

def socketio_service(request):
    socketio_manage(request.environ, {'/**wildcard**': ChatNamespace},
                    request)
```

So if wildcard namespace can be done, it would be convenient from defining long list of socketio.manage or is there any way to get resource values in gevent:

```
    //Obsolete version of socket.io
    var s = new io.Socket("c.tracking.com", {
        port: 85,
        resource: "server/%uid%",
```